# Is it possible to have multiple custom domains pointed at different github project pages (as well as the user page)?

Tags: url, github, dns

Does anyone here have experience with hosting multiple custom domain name sites from one github account–that is, the different custom urls point to different repositories that are project pages?

UPDATE:
Yes you can.

> For example, if I wanted my user page to be myname.com, and another
>   github project page to be anotherdifferentname.com, and another... is
>   this feasible? If I am correct, I would be using the same CNAME
>   (usrrname.github.io) on all the DNS settings domain registrar site,
>   and making A records that point to the usrrname.github.io "IN A" IP?
>
> I got that impression from the Github tutorial [Setting up custom
>   domain with
>   Pages](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-up-a-custom-domain-with-pages
>   "Setting up custom domain with Pages")
>
> My situation: I started off by making a project page with
>   alphagirls.cc directed to it (at
>   http://usrrname.github.io/alphagirls), and I'm interested in using a
>   custom url on my user page repo to host a personal website.

Comment: let me give this a try actually...

Comment: update: It works. It's possible to point multiple unique custom domain names to different project pages on github. Done!

Answer (score 1):

I think it's not possible. The [GitHub help page on setting pages has a section on project pages](https://help.github.com/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages#project-pages) which says:

> A custom domain on User and Organization Pages applies the same domain
>   redirect to all Project Pages hosted under that account. Project Pages
>   that use a custom domain are also available at
>   username.github.io/projectname

Comment: I made another repo on GH-pages, registered a domain on 1and1 and directed the A record to my GH-pages a-record and it worked! :) I'm going to transfer all my custom urls to different project pages now.